# How to start multiple SID at same time in oracle 11g

Tags: database, oracle11g, listener, instance, multiple-instances

I have created 4 listeners and 4 instances in a DB assigning different ports. I can able to up a single instance at a time using (Set ORACLE_SID = 'SID name').I need to up all 4 instances at same time. Is that possible, how can i do this ?

Comment: In a script? [Oracle even provides one](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/unxar/stopping-and-starting-oracle-software.html#GUID-1471DADF-6869-429F-AF5A-93FFA3DCE699). Or use HAS. Off-topic though really. Is there a reason you want/need a separate listener for each DB?

Comment: @AlexPoole You are right. If i 4 instance with one listener is that possible to start all 4 instance at the same time and it in windows 8 r2 OS.

Answer (score 0):

Simply, you can achieve by putting entries($ORACLE_SID:$ORACLE_HOME:) for all instances in /etc/oratab with some twik, don't follow $ORACLE_SID variable, instead you can hard code SID name.

Please refer following URL for the example:

https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/start%7Cstop-multiple-oracle-databases-in-the-same-oracle-server-422050/